# D3 force seems buggy after executing functions

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an problem, which I am trying to deal with for certain time already. if a node is clicked, a new node is added and attached. Which works fine. Also the force is applying to the new node. So far so good.

Further I added a context menu and binded the addNode() function. If a new node is created with help of this context menu, the force stops working. Its possible to add a bunch of nodes after but its necessary to drag any node to restart the force. It seems a bit random, but after the third or fourth node the error is there.

Any idea?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<html>

<head>
    <title>Index jFiddle</title>
    <!-- favcon -->
    <link rel="icon" href="https://networkrepository.com/favicon.png">
    <!-- call external d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
    <!-- Load context menu -->
    
    <!-- load "font awesome" stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/39094309d6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<style>
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0px;
        font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    }

    .canvas {
        background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
    }

    .link {
        stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    .node {
        stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    .icon {
        fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .node:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .tooltip {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 10px;
        background: rgb(245, 245, 245);
        border: 2px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        border-style: solid;
        pointer-events: none;
        line-height: 150%;
        padding: 8px 10px;
    }

    .d3-context-menu {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        border-radius: 4px;

        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        min-width: 150px;
        border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;

        z-index: 1200;
    }

    .d3-context-menu ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 4px 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        cursor: default;
    }

    .d3-context-menu ul li {
        padding: 4px 16px;
    }

    .d3-context-menu ul li:hover {
        background-color: #4677f8;
        color: #fefefe;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <svg id="svg"></svg>

    <!-- call app.js where the application is written -->
    <script>

        // define different variables
        var width = window.innerWidth
        height = window.innerHeight
        boolColor = true
        boolOpacity = true
        color = null
        nodes = null

        // define cavnas area to draw everything
        var svg = d3.select("svg")
            .attr("class", "canvas")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
                svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
            }))
            .append("g")

        // Removes zoom on doubleclick listener
        d3.select("svg").on("dblclick.zoom", null)

        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) { return d.id; }).distance(100))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-400))
            .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
            .force("attraceForce", d3.forceManyBody().strength(70));

        var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
            .attr("class", "tooltip")
            .style("opacity", 0);

        
            d3.contextMenu = function (menu, openCallback) {

// create the div element that will hold the context menu
d3.selectAll('.d3-context-menu').data([1])
    .enter()
    .append('div')
    .attr('class', 'd3-context-menu');

// close menu
d3.select('body').on('click.d3-context-menu', function() {
    d3.select('.d3-context-menu').style('display', 'none');
});

// this gets executed when a contextmenu event occurs
return function(data, index) {  
    var element = this;

    d3.selectAll('.d3-context-menu').html('');
    var list = d3.selectAll('.d3-context-menu').append('ul');
    list.selectAll('li')
        .data(menu)
        .enter()
            .append('li')
            .html(function(d) {
                return d.title;
            })
            .on('click', function(d, i) {
                d.action(element, data, index);
                d3.select('.d3-context-menu').style('display', 'none');
            });

    // the openCallback allows an action to fire before the menu is displayed
    // an example usage would be closing a tooltip
    if (openCallback) openCallback(data, index);

    // display context menu
    d3.select('.d3-context-menu')
        .style('left', (d3.event.pageX - 2) + 'px')
        .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 2) + 'px')
        .style('display', 'block');

    d3.event.preventDefault();
};
};
        


        var menu = [
            {
                title: 'Item #1',
                action: function (element, d, i) {
                    console.log('Item #1 clicked!');
                    console.log('The data for this circle is: ' + d);
                }
            },
            {
                title: 'AddNode',
                action: function (element,d ,i) {
                    addNode(d)
                    // re-initialize the simulation:
            simulation.nodes(data_nodes);
            simulation.force("link").links(data_links);
                }
            }
        ]

        // load data from json file
        var data_nodes = [
            {
                "id": "00000",
                "type": "company",
                "name": "Test",
                "context": [
                    { "name": "Ideal" }
                ],
                "icon": "\uf1ad"
            },
            {
                "id": "00100",
                "type": "software",
                "name": "Jira",
                "context": [
                    { "name": "Jira" }
                ],
                "icon": "\uf7b1",
                "parent": "00000"
            },
            {
                "id": "00200",
                "type": "software",
                "name": "Confluence",
                "context": [
                    { "name": "Confluence" }
                ],
                "icon": "\uf78d",
                "parent": "00000"
            },
            {
                "id": "00300",
                "type": "software",
                "name": "IVIS",
                "context": [
                    { "name": "IVIS" }
                ],
                "icon": "\ue084",
                "parent": "00000"
            },
            {
                "id": "00400",
                "type": "software",
                "name": "IPOS",
                "context": [
                    { "name": "IPOS"}
                ],
                "icon": "\ue084",
                "parent": "00000"
            },
            {
                "id": "00500",
                "type": "software",
                "name": "IDAS",
                "context": [
                    { "name": "IDAS" }
                ],
                "icon": "\ue084",
                "parent": "00000"
            },
            {
                "id": "99997",
                "type": "hardware",
                "name": "power-plug",
                "context": [
                    { "name": "power-plug" }
                ],
                "icon": "\uf1e6",
                "parent": "00000"
            },
            {
                "id": "99998",
                "type": "hardware",
                "name": "usv",
                "context": [
                    { "name": "usv" }
                ],
                "icon": "\uf5df",
                "parent": "00000"
            },
        ]

        var data_links = [

            { "source": "99998", "target": "00000" },
            { "source": "99997", "target": "00000" },
            { "source": "00100", "target": "00000" },
            { "source": "00200", "target": "00000" },
            { "source": "00300", "target": "00000" },
            { "source": "00400", "target": "00000" },
            { "source": "00500", "target": "00000" },

        ]



        // create links which visualize relationships
        var links = svg.selectAll("svg")
            .data(data_links)
            .enter()
            .append("line")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .style("stroke-width", 3)
            .style("stroke-linecap", "round")

        var nodes = svg.selectAll("svg")
            .data(data_nodes)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("r", 30)
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("fill", initialColor)
            .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragStarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragEnded)
            )
            .on("click", click)
            .on("mouseenter", mouseEnter)
            .on("mouseleave", mouseLeave)
            .on("contextmenu", d3.contextMenu(menu))



        var icons = svg.selectAll("svg")
            .data(data_nodes)
            .enter()
            //.append("g")
            .append("text")
            .attr("class", "icon")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
            .style("font-family", "FontAwesome")
            .style("font-size", "30px")
            .text(function (d) { return d.icon; })
            .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragStarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragEnded)
            )

        simulation.nodes(data_nodes).on("tick", ticked);

        simulation.force("link").links(data_links);


        function click(d) {
            addNode(d)
        }


        function addNode(d) {
            var id = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);

            var newLink = { source: id, target: d.id }
            data_links.push(newLink);

            var obj = {
                "id": id,
                "type": "company",
                "name": "Test1",
                "context": [
                    { "name": "Jira"}
                ],
                "icon": "\uf1ad"
            }
            data_nodes.push(obj)
            // changes:

            var newLink = { source: id, target: d.id }
            data_links.push(newLink);


            links = svg.selectAll("line")
                .data(data_links)
                .enter()
                .append("line")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .style("stroke-width", 3)
                .style("stroke-linecap", "round")
                // disable browser context menu on link       
                .merge(links);

            //append the new object:
            nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(data_nodes)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("r", 30)
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("fill", initialColor)
                .call(d3.drag()
                    .on("start", dragStarted)
                    .on("drag", dragged)
                    .on("end", dragEnded)
                )
                .on("click", click)
                .on("mouseenter", mouseEnter)
                .on("mouseleave", mouseLeave)
                .on("contextmenu", d3.contextMenu(menu))
                .merge(nodes);

            icons = svg.selectAll("text")
                .data(data_nodes)
                .enter()
                .append("text")
                .attr("class", "icon")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
                .style("font-family", "FontAwesome")
                .style("font-size", "30px")
                .text(function (d) { return d.icon; })
                .call(d3.drag()
                    .on("start", dragStarted)
                    .on("drag", dragged)
                    .on("end", dragEnded)
                )
                .merge(icons);


            // re-initialize the simulation:
            simulation.nodes(data_nodes);
            simulation.force("link").links(data_links);

        }

        function mouseEnter(d) {
            color = d3.select(this).style("fill")

            if (d.name === "power-plug") {
                d3.select(this)
                    .attr("r", 40)
            } else if (d.name === "usv" || d.name === "diesel") {
                d3.select(this)
                    .attr("r", 40)
                tooltip.transition()
                    .style("opacity", 1);
                tooltip.html(
                    "ID: " + d.id + "<br/>" +
                    "Name: " + d.name + "<br/>" +
                    "Typ: " + d.type + "<br/>" +
                    "Context: " + d.context)
                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 90) + "px");
            } else {
                d3.select(this)
                    .attr("r", 40)
                    .style("fill", "lightblue")
                tooltip.transition()
                    .style("opacity", 1);
                tooltip.html(
                    "ID: " + d.id + "<br/>" +
                    "Name: " + d.name + "<br/>" +
                    "Typ: " + d.type + "<br/>" +
                    "Context: " + d.context)
                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 90) + "px");
            }
        }

        /*
        Controls the behavior of each object as soon as the cursor leaves.
        Radius and color will is set to the default values. Further the tooltip
        opacity is set to 0, which hides the tooltip again.
        */
        function mouseLeave(d) {
            // Exclude tooltip from object "power-plug"
            if (d.name === "power-plug") {
                d3.select(this)
                    .attr("r", 30)
            } else {
                nodes.filter((n) => {
                    return n.context == d.context
                }).style("fill", color)
                    .attr("r", 30)
                tooltip.transition()
                    .style("opacity", 0);
            }
        }


        function ticked() {
            // update link positions
            links
                .attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });

            // update node positions
            nodes
                .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
                .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })

            // update icon positions
            icons
                .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x })
                .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y })

        }

        /*
            Set the color of each node in dependency of their d.name attribute.
        */
        function initialColor(d) {
            switch (d.name) {
                case "power-plug":
                    return "lightgreen"
                case "usv":
                    return "orange"
                default:
                    return "whitesmoke"
            }
        }

        /*
            dragStarted() / dragged() and dragEnded() controlling the drag behaviour of each
            object. In case all drag events are not desired, simple comment out the .call(d3.drag())
            execution during the object(node) creation
        */
        function dragStarted(d) {
            if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d.fx = d.x;
            d.fy = d.y;
        }

        function dragged(d) {
            d.fx = d3.event.x;
            d.fy = d3.event.y;
        }

        function dragEnded(d) {
            if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
            d.fx = null;
            d.fy = null;
        }






    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be that the simulation is not being "reheated" when adding a new node with the context menu. Reheating the simulation is a "soft restart" process that makes the nodes move again, which is needed when adding new data or during interactions. Without reheating, the interaction only works while the simulation is still active (i.e, when the alpha haven't decayed to 0 yet). This is why the first nodes are ok, and the third or fourth are buggy: by that time, the simulation already settled and it will not move by itself anymore.

You are already reheating the simulation when there is a drag start event (`dragStarted`):

```js
if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart()
```

This is setting the `alphaTarget` of the simulation to 0.3 and restarting the simulation, which means that it will keep the `alpha` around 0.3, making the simulation constantly move as `alpha` never decays to 0. At drag end the `alphaTarget` is set back to 0, so it settles again after some time. This is why the forces return after drag interactions.

What you need is to also reheat the simulation after adding a node through the context menu. However, since there is no "end" event for adding a node, you might want to use `.alpha` instead of `.alphaTarget`

```js
{
  title: 'AddNode',
  action: function (element,d ,i) {
    addNode(d)
    // re-initialize the simulation:
    simulation.nodes(data_nodes);
    simulation.force("link").links(data_links);
    simulation.alpha(0.3).restart()
  }
}
```

This sets the `alpha` of the simulation back to 0.3, which will force it to adjust a little bit before decaying back to 0. You can lower the 0.3 if you feel the nodes are moving too much after adding a new node, or increase it if you feel the nodes are not moving enough.

Also, I noticed there is already a `// simulation restart` part at the end of the `.addNode` function, so the one in the code segment above is a little redundant. This is not the problem this time, but you might want to remove the outside one and keep only the one inside `.addNode` to avoid bugs in the future.